# Proof for Knuth Optimization

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Knuth Optimization states that if the DP equation satisfies 
$$OPT(i,j)=\min_{i<k\leq j}\{OPT(i,k-1)+OPT(k,j)\}+w(i,j)$$
and $w(i,j)$ satisfies for any integer $0<a<b<c<d$
$$w[a,c]+w[b,d]\leq w[a,d]+w[b,c]\\
w[b,c]\leq w[a,d]$$

Then we have 
$$OPT(a,c)+OPT(b,d)\leq OPT(a,d)+OPT(b,c)$$
and
$$K(i,j-1)\leq K(i,j)\leq K(i+1,j)$$
where 
$$K(i,j)=\text{arg }\min_{i<k\leq j}\{OPT(i,k-1)+OPT(k,j)\}$$
How to prove the first inequality?

Comment: Maybe you should put scare-quotes around the words "We all know." Kai-Lai Chung's undergraduate textbook on probability says $$ \text{“Everybody knows'' that } e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

Comment: This is Lemma 2.1 in Yao's [Efficient dynamic programming using quadrangle inequalities](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/800141.804691).

Answer (score -1):

See here for a nice Explanation:

http://home.cse.ust.hk/~golin/COMP572/Notes/DP_speedup.pdf